# How to run cucumber tests through centrally hosted web pages to extend the possibility of being able to pick and run desired test cases

Tags: selenium, cucumber

There should be a way where user should be able to access test cases and select or customize them online before running. Or in simple terms is it easy to use feature files online.

Comment: Please give more context to your question. What have you already tried? Can you further elaborate on your question?

Comment: for this scenario, you have to create a single page web application and it should have the option to select the feature file/s and run it. we had same scenario and create a web page using nodejs and it will give option to select feature files and run.

Comment: This question is too broad and too vague for me to give a useful answer as it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  A specific example would help perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/index.html)

After you set up your Jenkins server you can access it though a web page, create jobs, and run them. There are also reporting plug-ins like [Cucumber Reports](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cucumber+Reports+Plugin) that make nice, easy to read, reports.